# Add legend based on line types and colors in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created the following plot using `plot()` function and I would like to convert it to `ggplot()` and add colors in the line types like:

[image]

and also a legend for `'predicted'` (normal line) and `'observed'` values (dashed line) like:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
# Creating some data first
scoregroepen <- seq(from = 1, to = 8, by = 1)
s_toets_observed <- c(0.18, 0.31, 0.42, 0.53, 0.64,0.75,0.84,0.95)
s_toets_predicted <- c(0.20, 0.29, 0.40, 0.55, 0.66, 0.75, 0.85, 0.94)
s_toets_conf_low <- s_toets_observed-0.03
s_toets_conf_high <- s_toets_observed+0.045

plot(scoregroepen,s_toets_predicted, type="b", ylab = "proporties", ylim = c(0,1))
lines(scoregroepen, s_toets_observed, type="b", lty = 2 )
lines(scoregroepen, s_toets_conf_low, lty = 2 )
lines(scoregroepen, s_toets_conf_high, lty = 2 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this which is close to what you expect. I have re arranged your variables in a dataframe to reshape them and then sketch the plot. Here the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
# Creating some data first
scoregroepen <- seq(from = 1, to = 8, by = 1)
s_toets_observed <- c(0.18, 0.31, 0.42, 0.53, 0.64,0.75,0.84,0.95)
s_toets_predicted <- c(0.20, 0.29, 0.40, 0.55, 0.66, 0.75, 0.85, 0.94)
s_toets_conf_low <- s_toets_observed-0.03
s_toets_conf_high <- s_toets_observed+0.045
df <- data.frame(scoregroepen,s_toets_observed,s_toets_predicted,
                 s_toets_conf_low,s_toets_conf_high)
#Plot
df %>% pivot_longer(-scoregroepen) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=scoregroepen,y=value,color=name,linetype=name))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_point(aes(shape=name))+
  scale_color_manual(values=c('blue','blue','tomato','cyan3'),
                     breaks=c('s_toets_observed','s_toets_predicted'),
                     labels=c('Observed','Predicted'))+
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(NA,NA,1,4),
                     breaks=c('s_toets_observed','s_toets_predicted'),
                     labels=c('Observed','Predicted'))+
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c('dotted','dotted','dashed','solid'),
                        breaks=c('s_toets_observed','s_toets_predicted'),
                        labels=c('Observed','Predicted'))+
  labs(color='var',shape='var',linetype='var')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: good answer but could you turn it to observer and predicted in the legend instead of s_toets in front of them and also add different colors to the lines?

Comment: @firmo23 For sure! Just a moment!

Comment: @firmo23 Updated, let me know if that works :)